# Crosswalk errors trying to load JNI libraries

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

The following errors appear when my Android app is starting up:

```
09-06 12:40:56.787 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libavformat-55.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
09-06 12:40:56.792 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libavformat-55.so
09-06 12:40:56.792 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libxwalkdummy.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
09-06 12:40:56.792 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libxwalkdummy.so
09-06 12:40:56.797 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libswresample-0.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
09-06 12:40:56.797 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libswresample-0.so
09-06 12:40:56.802 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libgnustl_shared.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
09-06 12:40:56.807 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libgnustl_shared.so
09-06 12:40:56.812 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libswscale-2.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
09-06 12:40:56.812 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libswscale-2.so
09-06 12:40:56.827 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libFFmpegWrapper.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
09-06 12:40:56.827 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libFFmpegWrapper.so
09-06 12:40:56.832 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libavutil-52.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
09-06 12:40:56.832 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libavutil-52.so
09-06 12:40:56.837 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libavcodec-55.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
09-06 12:40:56.837 12976-13134/com.company.MyApp.debug W/chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.company.MyApp.debug-10/libavcodec-55.so
```

The files are all architecture-specific files under jniLibs.

Why is Crosswalk loading (or attempting to load) these libraries? And what impact does not being able to load them have?

Answer (score 0):

I managed it to resolve by installing lite mode of crosswalk plugin running following command.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview  --variable XWALK_MODE="lite"`